# Can we overload a function based on only whether a parameter is a value or a reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, overloading, pass-by-value

I got the answer NO! Because passing by value and passing by reference looks identical to the caller.

However, the code below compiles right

```
class A {

public:
void f(int i) {}    

void f(int& i) {}
};
```

But when I try to use it, there is compile error.

```
int main () {

   A a;
   int i = 9;
   int& j = i;
   a.f(1);
   a.f(i);
   a.f(j);
  return 0;
}
```

Why does not the compiler disable it even without knowing it is going to be used?

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual compiler error and line number.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930323/f5-and-int-x-fx-to-call-different-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can be overloaded based on reference or not. That is why it's perfectly fine to have them coexist like that; they are different.

The problem has to do with ambiguity. While `f(1)` can only be called on one variation, `f(i)` can be called on both. Neither is preferable, therefore you get an error for ambiguity. If you added a third function, `foo (const int&)`, **all** calls would be ambiguous. But all are still overloads of each other, and non-conflicting.

I agree it's strange to be able to have three overloads of a function, and be able to directly call none. Perhaps someone else has more to add.

Answer (score 9):

You can call each method:

```
void (A::*t)(int& ) =&A::f;
A a;
int i = 9;
int& j = i;   
a.f(1); //  f(int i)
(a.*t)(i); // f(int& i)
```

Comment: `(a.*f)(i);` should be sufficient.

Comment: you probably meant (a.*t)(i); (not (a.*f))

Comment: Yes, i was fixed on what i was going to add.

Comment: Could you explain this ?

Comment: @ShivanshJagga : just declaring a pointer to member function that takes reference to int (and returns void).  Then calling the method through pointer ---  (a.*t)(i);